# Merge data.table with diff nrows such that the shorter dataset repeats the last row till equal length of other

Tags: r, dplyr, sas, data.table

I am not able to relate the output of the function merge in SAS with any of the concepts that I know i.e. inner, outer, left or right outer, cross join or anti join.
I am trying to get the output in R but not sure how to go about it.

The code merges two datsets using a single variable. That variable has the same single value in both the datasets. My understanding is that it must be a one to many merge but the output has same number of rows as the second dataset.

**SAS Code**

```
data xyz;
merge dt1(in = INA) dt2(in = INB);
by STUDENT;
```

or

```
data xyz;
   merge dt1(in = INA) dt2(in = INB);
   by STUDENT;
   if INA = 1; 
run;
```

**My R Code**

```
dt2<- data.frame(Student = c(6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6),

             RollNum2 = c(58,69,45, 38,88,73,33,99,29),

             Marks2= c(8,9,10,3,5,7,8,8,9))


dt1<- data.frame(Student = c(6,6,6),

             RollNum1 = c(49,69,44),

             Marks1= c(8,9,10))
```

I Tried

```
xyz <- merge(x   = dt1,
             y   = dt2,
             by  = "Student"
             all = TRUE,
             allow.cartesian = TRUE)
```

or

```
xyz <- merge(x   = dt1,
             y   = dt2,
             by  = "STUDENT"
             all.x = TRUE,
             allow.cartesian = TRUE)
```

or

```
xyz <- left_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("STUDENT"))
```

**INPUT**

*dt1*

Student        RollNum1    Marks1

```
 6         49             8

 6         69             9

 6         44            10
```

*dt2*

Student     RollNum2       Marks2

```
 6          58             8

 6          69             9

 6          45            10

 6          38             3

 6          88             5

 6          73             7

 6          33             8

 6          99             8

 6          29             9
```

**OUTPUT**

*DESIRED OUTPUT (AS IT COMES IN SAS)*

STUDENT RollNum1    Marks1  RollNum1    Marks2

```
 6          49     8       58              8

 6          69     9       69              9

 6          44    10       45              10

 6          44    10       38              3

 6          44    10       88              5

 6          44    10       73              7

 6          44    10       33              8

 6          44    10       99              8

 6          44    10       29              9
```

As we can see the first two rows of dt1 binds with first two rows of dt2 and for the rest of rows the third row of dt1 binds with all the rows of dt2. The final output number of rows is same as number of rows of dt2.

**R output with left merge/join (NOT DESIRED OUTPUT)**

*OUTPUT (NOT DESIRED - One to many results with 27 rows)*

student roll.no.x marks2.x roll.no.y marks2.y

1:       6        49        8        58        8

2:       6        49        8        69        9

3:       6        49        8        45       10

4:       6        49        8        38        3

5:       6        49        8        88        5

6:       6        49        8        73        7

7:       6        49        8        33        8

8:       6        49        8        99        8

9:       6        49        8        29        9

10:       6        69        9        58        8

11:       6        69        9        69        9

12:       6        69        9        45       10

13:       6        69        9        38        3

14:       6        69        9        88        5

15:       6        69        9        73        7

16:       6        69        9        33        8

17:       6        69        9        99        8

18:       6        69        9        29        9

19:       6        44       10        58        8

20:       6        44       10        69        9

21:       6        44       10        45       10

22:       6        44       10        38        3

23:       6        44       10        88        5

24:       6        44       10        73        7

25:       6        44       10        33        8

26:       6        44       10        99        8

27:       6        44       10        29        9

Comment: Add an extra variable that numbers each observation with in each STUDENT value,  call ROW for example.  Then join add match on ROW to criteria. If you want to have the last row for smaller groups repeated then adjust the join criteria.  Something like: `a.row=b.row or (a.row=max(a.row) and a.row < b.row) or (b.row=max(b.row) and a.row > b.row)`

Comment: The code given by Carles works perfectly for one set of "Student". What if there are different values of student? How to group by "student" and then do "LastRowrep" for each group and then bind into one?

Answer (score 2):

In SAS, the (in = variable_name) statement allows you to control the type of your merge. dt1(in = INA) creates a variable that is 1 in the data set dt1, and dt2(in = INB) does the same for data set 2.

Through if statements, you can now control which observations you want to keep after the merge. If you set "if INA = 1;", only rows that were contained in dt1 are kept. That is equivalent to a left_merge in R. If you set "if INA = 1;" and "if INB = 1;", that would be the equivalent of an inner merge as you would only keep students in both data sets.
E.g. the following below would be a left merge:

```
proc sort dt1; by STUDENT; run; 
proc sort dt2; by STUDENT; run;    

data xyz;
   merge dt1(in = INA) dt2(in = INB);
   by STUDENT;
   if INA = 1; 
run;
```

Carles Sans Fuentes has provided a dplyr translation of the SAS code above.

Comment: Thanks Fischer! But in SAS it's a left join but the same result is not obtained by a left join in R. Either with merge(all.x = TRUE) or left_join. The R gives a one to many merge result with 27 number of rows(3 * 9)

Answer (score 2):

Is your question HOW the SAS data step you showed is combining the data?

The MERGE **statement** (it is NOT a function) in SAS will read one observation from each input on each iteration of the data step.  When one input runs out of observations for that group no more are read from that input until the next group. So the values of the variables contributed by that source do not change.

When a new group starts (based on the values of the BY variables) then all the variables are cleared. So if one input does not have any observations for that group then the variables unique to that input will be missing.

If you have non BY variables in common between the inputs then the value loaded last will override the earlier values.  The values are loaded from the inputs in the order they are listed in the MERGE statement.  So in your case if DT1 and DT2 both have a variable named FRED then the values loaded from DT2 will overwrite the values read from DT1.  But if DT1 has more observations for a group than DT2 then the new values for FRED from DT1 will be loaded, but not overwritten by values from DT2 since it has stopped contributing data for this group.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the existence of a function which does that.

Nevertheless, as I see it, you could make a function such that:

1. Selecting those variables which have the column `Student`
2. Repeating in `dt1` the last observation until the same `nrow(dt2)`
3. Binding rows in `dt1`
4. Binding `dt1` and `dt2` by column
5. Remove one of the `Student` columns

This should be done by each unique value in column `Student`.

For you see the inner part of it, this could be done by:

```
dt1<- data.frame(Student = c(6,6,6,7,7), 
                 RollNum1 = c(49,69,44,86,39), 
                 Marks1= c(8,9,10,8,5)) 
dt2<- data.frame(Student = c(6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7), 
                 RollNum2 = c(58,69,45,38,88,73,33,99,29,58,31,55,58,44,56,89), 
                 Marks2= c(8,9,10,3,5,7,8,8,9,6,9,5,9,3,4,8))

uniquevars<- unique(dt1$Student)
for(i in 1:length(uniquevars)){
  subsetdt1<- dt1[dt1$Student==uniquevars[i],]
  subsetdt2<- dt2[dt2$Student==uniquevars[i],]
  LastRowrep<-as.data.frame(matrix(rep(unlist(subsetdt1[nrow(subsetdt1),]),times=nrow(subsetdt2)-nrow(subsetdt1)),ncol = ncol(subsetdt1), byrow = T))
  colnames(LastRowrep)<-colnames(subsetdt1)
  if(i ==1){Res<-cbind(rbind(subsetdt1,LastRowrep),subsetdt2)}
  else{Res<-rbind(Res,cbind(rbind(subsetdt1,LastRowrep),subsetdt2))}

}
Res
   Student RollNum1 Marks1 Student RollNum2 Marks2
1        6       49      8       6       58      8
2        6       69      9       6       69      9
3        6       44     10       6       45     10
4        6       44     10       6       38      3
5        6       44     10       6       88      5
6        6       44     10       6       73      7
7        6       44     10       6       33      8
8        6       44     10       6       99      8
9        6       44     10       6       29      9
42       7       86      8       7       58      6
52       7       39      5       7       31      9
11       7       39      5       7       55      5
21       7       39      5       7       58      9
31       7       39      5       7       44      3
41       7       39      5       7       56      4
51       7       39      5       7       89      8
```

Cheers !

Comment: But a left join would give me 27 rows which shouldn't happen for the desired output. Thenumber of rows in final should be equal to number of rows in dt2.

Comment: Thanks Carles! This makes sense to get the exact output. Was just wondering why such a difference would exist between two platform for the same logic.

Comment: what if there are different students and I want to do this operation for each STUDENT set separately and then bind into one?

Comment: then you can just implement in a function a variable called `column` for instance where you do `unique(column)` to get the unique cases (that would be case 1 in my explanation up, and then as a 6th one you can create a new frame where you bind by row the datasets. Answering your first question about the logic:  I do not see the purpose of repeating the last observation in SAS to make it match with the other matrix in size. With NAs would make sense, but not that way (that is my modest opinion)

Comment: Thanks Carles! as for the logic, I am also not convinced why the repetation occurs but in SAS this is how the merge statement results to.

Comment: @Charles can you please assist if the table was like below: ```

dt1<- data.table(Student = c(6,6,6,7,7),

            RollNum1 = c(49,69,44,86,39),

            Marks1= c(8,9,10,8,5))

dt2<- data.table(Student = c(6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7),

             RollNum2 = c(58,69,45,38,88,73,33,99,29,58,31,55,58,44,56,89),

             Marks2= c(8,9,10,3,5,7,8,8,9,6,9,5,9,3,4,8))

 
```  and I want to group by student values and then do the rep action?

Comment: I reedited it up. The code is not really optimized, but I hope it does the trick for your to see how it is done.

Comment: This makes things very clear. Thanks again Charles!